# Websocket progress pauses when switching tabs on browser (client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I face quite an extraordinary side effect I never faced before. Let me describe it thoroughly:

Client (browser) has an input tag, where files are being chosen. On clicking a specific button, an action emits, where those files are being transmitted to the server by websockets (by library Socket.io).

```
// Starts an upload after clicking on an upload button.
async upload() {
    if (this.state.fileList.length === 0) { return; }

    // Dispatch a start uploading action.
    this.props.startUp();

    // We map original files from the state's file list.
    let originFiles = _.map(this.state.fileList, (file: any) => {
        return file.originFileObj;
    });

    // Send files over the socket streams to the server.
    await ApiService.upload(originFiles, () => {
        // Update the state whenever a file has been uploaded.
        this.setState({ ...this.state, finishedFiles: this.state.finishedFiles + 1 })
    });

    this.clearItemList();
    // Dispatch an end uploading action.
    this.props.endUp();
}
```

This function is called whenever the button is clicked. As you can see, there is an api service, that gets called on that filelist, and streams those files to the server. The files are streamed through the sockets.

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import * as ios from 'socket.io-stream';

export function upload(data: any[], onUpload?: () => void): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const up = io.connect("ws://localhost:8000/");
        // Right after we connect.
        up.on('connect', () => {
            // Connect to the upload socket point.
            up.emit('upload', {});
            // Whenever we receive an 'ok' status, we send files over the wire.
            up.on('ok', async () => {
                // If we sent all the files, notify the server to end.
                if (data.length === 0) {
                    up.emit('end', {});
                    up.disconnect();
                    // Resolve this promise.
                    res();
                // Otherwise, emit a 'data' action, that sends the files.
                } else {
                    let blob = data.pop();
                    let stream = ios.createStream();
                    ios(up).emit('data', stream, { size: blob.size });
                    ios.createBlobReadStream(blob, { highWaterMark: 500000 }).pipe(stream);
                    // Callback for the onUpload event.
                    onUpload();
                }
            });
            up.on('error', () => {
                rej();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Everything works well, until I switch tabs on the client (browser) and the progress gets paused. After I switch to the client tab, the progress automatically resumes.

My colleague presumed, this might be a problem with a browser itself, which stops the files to be piped whenever I lose focus of the tab.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem and/or tweak the code a bit will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If your system is low on memory and you are using Chrome, you may want to consider checking out `chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding`.

Comment: I've tried to disable this option, but still, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't pause the stream, it slows it down only. check this option in Chrome: "--disable-background-timer-throttling"