# Does the frequency of websocket data transfer delays when switched to a different tab?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io, node-websockets

I have a react app where i send data to a websocket every 30 milliseconds when a button is pressed. i have the websocket connection in a context so that i can keep sending the data even when i am on a different page. But when i switch tabs (because i have another app running at the same time on a different tab and i need to use that app inbetween), the data transferred to the websocket seems to be delayed. Why is that ? Is there any way to keep sending the data at the same frequency even when i am on a different tab ?

Here's my backend code-

```
const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8090 });

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log(`Received: ${message}`);
  });
});
```

Here's my React app-

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const WebSocketContext = createContext();

export function useWebSocket() {
  return useContext(WebSocketContext);
}

export function WebSocketProvider({ children }) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const [robotControls, setRobotControls] = useState(false);
  const webSocketURL =
    import.meta.env.VITE_ENV == "UXV"
      ? "ws://localhost:8090/chat"
      : "ws://localhost:8090";

  useEffect(() => {
    // Connect to the WebSocket server
    const ws = new WebSocket(webSocketURL);

    ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
      console.log("Connected to the WebSocket server");
      setConnected(true);
      setSocket(ws);
    });

    return () => {
      // Clean up WebSocket connection when component unmounts
      ws.close();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval1;
    let i = 0;
    if (robotControls) {
      interval1 = setInterval(() => {
        const time = new Date().getMilliseconds();
        //console.log(time)
        socket.send(time);
      }, 30);
    }

    return () => {
      if (interval1) {
        clearInterval(interval1);
      }
    };
  }, [robotControls]);


  const contextValue = {
    connected,
    socket,
    sendMessage,
    robotControls, 
    setRobotControls
  };


  return (
    <WebSocketContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </WebSocketContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I tried socketio library to see if it amkes any difference, but i get the same result.

Edit:
I have edited my frontend code above. The node server i use is just a test server that i use to troubleshoot the websocket connection.

To provide more context to this, i am developing a frontend offline app using react where i use this app with a controller to control/move a robot. The backend (developing by someone else) for this robot expects controller data which i am planning to send through web sockets to control the robot. I am sending data with 30 ms for testing. i haven't tested the code with the actual backend server yet. There is another web application that works alongside my application, which is why i need my app to send data through websockets even if i am on the other application. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You should add details, like what is the device, the browser etc. This question has been asked multiple times, browsers implement delays on timers when a tab is inactive (sockets, setTimeout etc). Sometimes there is a solution like [here for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760816/websocket-progress-pauses-when-switching-tabs-on-browser-client). It also seems weird to me to have to send data each 30ms, maybe it's an XY problem and there is a better solution? So details would be welcome

Comment: Inactive tabs might be subject to throttling, see answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs - you didn't include the code that runs every 30 secs, but if it is an setInterval, you might be affected by this throttling. Web workers might help you out here.

Comment: Thanks for the help @timotgl. Using the script from that link fixed the issue. (http://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer). Its a solution using webworkers which overrides functions setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval, clearInterval.

Answer (score 0):

On most browsers inactive tabs have low priority execution and this can affect JavaScript timers. Using Web Workers API will be one of the solution in this case.

I fixed this by adding this script before any javascript codes. ([github.com/turuslan/HackTimer](https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer)). Its a solution using webworkers which overrides functions setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval, clearInterval.